# How to pass payload in POST V1/invoices when i generate invoice of bundle product in Magento-2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, partial-invoice

I want to generate invoice for bundle product. I don't know what data is pass for generate invoice for bundle product. Please tell me which data is passed,when i create invoice using POST V1/invoices in Magento-2.1.

Comment: anybody help me..